# IIS site down after disabling TLS 1.2

Tags: iis, tls1.2

I have an IIS helpdesk system (3rd party so I don't have code access) running on Windows Server 2019 and IIS 10. One of the features it has is to connect to mailboxes via IMAP. When we try and use this it gives us an SSL error.

I was advised by our exchange team that the exchange server uses TLS 1.2, so I enabled it on the server. However, our network team have since advised that the connection attempt is actually being made via TLS 1.0 so I need to ensure TLS 1.1 and 1.2 are disabled on the app server.

I enabled TLS 1.0 and disabled TLS 1.1 without any issues, however when I disable TLS 1.2, the web page for the helpdesk system goes down and just gives an HTTP 500 error. Only when I re-enable TLS 1.2 does it start working again.

I found a few pages on Google of things to try, such as removing and re-adding the bindings in IIS after disabling TLS 1.2 but this hasn't worked.

Any idea why disabling TLS 1.2 breaks the web page? TLS 1.2 was disabled when I first installed the helpdesk system the page worked fine then. According to the vendor of the system, it just uses the TLS version configured on the server, so why does it seem to rely on 1.2? Is there a setting somewhere in IIS that tells it which version to use that needs updating? I didn't have to set anything when I enabled 1.2.

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0):

> ... that the connection attempt is actually being made via TLS 1.0 so I need to ensure TLS 1.1 and 1.2 are disabled on the app server

This  conclusion is wrong. TLS versions are not exclusiv to each other. To support TLS 1.0 clients you need to enable TLS 1.0, but keep TLS 1.1 and TLS 1.2 enabled.

Comment: Sorry I'm not familiar with how TLS works - does this mean 1.1 and 1.2 MUST be enabled for 1.0 to work? Many thanks,

Comment: @TomCamish: *"1.1 and 1.2 MUST be enabled for 1.0 to work"* - In theory no, in practice there might be side effects. It is not expected that one enables weaker TLS versions and disables stronger ones. This makes no actual sense. One might enable weaker TLS versions in addition to stronger TLS versions in order to support older TLS clients, but one should still keep the stronger versions enabled for newer clients or in order to communicate from the server with other systems.

Comment: Thank you for your advice. It sounds like this isn't going to work - my web application seems to want to make the outgoing IMAP connection via TLS 1.2, however as the exchange server is so old it wants TLS 1.0 and fails.

Comment: @TomCamish: as I said - don't disable TLS 1.2. Just keep TLS 1.0, TLS 1.1 and TLS 1.2 enabled.

Answer (score 0):

You can support both TLS 1.0 and TLS 1.2. Which one is actually used also depends on the other end. Configuring 1.2 everywhere will make it work with 1.2, but you can also leave 1.0 on in case you miss a device that is still using 1.0. TLS is backward compatible. Systems using TLS1.1 and TLS1.0 will continue to function when TLS1.2 is enabled, so if any of your processing requires TLS1.0 and TLS1.1, it will remain available. Nonetheless, it is recommended that your developers upgrade to only run on TLS 1.2. This is necessary because current security standards no longer consider TLS 1.0 and TLS 1.1 to be secure.